# Crystal Reports -Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset. ADO.Net xml

Tags: .net, xml, crystal-reports, oledb

Okay here is the scenario I have a VB6 application that is getting re-written for asp.net 3.5.  I have a grundle of Crystal Reports that are getting updated to Crystal Reports 10.5 (which is included in Visual Studio 2008).  All of the old reports used OLEDB.  What I am doing is taking the sql statements used in the reports and putting them in the database.  I next run an automated process to create a Dataset from those select statements and I serialize the DataSet and save the schema and data as an XML document.  I then go into the old report update it to Crystal Reports 10.5 and change the Data Source location so that it uses the XML document.

When the report is run I create the same DataSet and instead of serializing it as XML I assign it to the report (see below)

```
 rd.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ds)
```

I have tested this and do not get any errors if I create the report new but if I take an existing report and change the database location I get the following error

Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset. Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\username\LOCALS~1\Temp\R-302 {D49E0C73-47AC-4363-AAD5-E925DFCF446E}.rpt: Invalid argument for database.
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e) at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream

It seems as if the report is still trying to connect using OLEDB to the old database.  I have been able to get a report to work if I rewrite it using the exact same logic but the updated reports through the above error.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this here because it's the top result for "Invalid Argument Provided Crystal".

I was working within Crystal Reports XI on a report that was linked to a datasource that I was trying to change via the GUI. Selecting the new datasource and clicking Update would appear to do nothing and I would close the dialog, at which point I would receive the message "Invalid Argument Provided". I tried many things before eventually **closing and reopening the file**, which worked when I tried again.

This allowed me to modify the datasource without removing any of the associated fields.

My work PC stays logged in/switched on/locked 24/7 for VPN purposes and I'd opened the report in question the previous day. My guess here is that a connection to the SQL instance had timed out and was not being re-established.

My apologies for necro'ing this old question, or if this was the wrong thing to do; but given the page's prominence in search results I'm hopeful that this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and context (Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2008).
Using my new connexion in a new report was fine but assigning this same connexion to an old report (with "Set Datasource Location") got me this error when using the report with the function ExportToStream.

What I finally did was going to "Database Expert", removed my connexion and saying "OK" to the "Remove File" box "There are fields in the report from this file. Continue?" Doing this removed all fields in the report. I has to re-insert them and re-choose the fields for my groups, but at least, I didn't have to redo all the layout.

I guess, it's a bug in Crystal Report for Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error with older connection.

Resolution :

- Open the sub-report wizard
- Create new connection
- Use new connection for creating sub-reports